# How to use Callout together with NominalScale?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Using MM13.1 on Windows

How can I use `callout` together with `NominalScale`?
I would have thought this could work but it doesn't.

```
  ListPlot[{{0, "Heads"}, Callout[{1, "Tails"}, "Label"], {2, "Tails"}},
  ScalingFunctions -> NominalScale[{"Heads", "Tails"}]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{{0, 2}, Callout[{1, 1}, "Label"], {2, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like an unimplemented functionality (formally a bug). Worth reporting to the support.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{0, "Heads"}, Callout[{1, "Tails"}, "Label"], {2, "Tails"}};

ListPlot[
 data /. {"Heads" -> 2, "Tails" -> 1},
 Ticks -> {Automatic,
   {{1, "Tails"}, {2, "Heads"}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround I was hoping to not needed to go there. Anyway I'll report the "bug" to Wolfram